# css with cackePHP not working

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code:

```
<ul class="grid cs-style-7">
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/6.png" alt="img06">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Game Center</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1118904-Game-Center">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/4.png" alt="img04">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Settings</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/2.png" alt="img02">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Music</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1115960-Music">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/5.png" alt="img05">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Safari</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116775-Safari">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/1.png" alt="img01">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Camera</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1115632-Camera">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/3.png" alt="img03">
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Phone</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1117308-Phone">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /container -->
```

Also i have this cackePHP code:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($popular_properties)) {
?>
<div class="container block-space">
          <h3 class="dc bot-space bot-mspace"><?php echo __l("Popular Properties"); ?></h3>
          <div class="ver-space clearfix">
            <ol class="text-16 span8 no-mar clearfix unstyled graydarkc">
<?php
    $z = 0;
    foreach($popular_properties as $property) {
        $z++;
        $class = "secondary";
        if($z%3 == 1) {
            $class = "default";
        } else if($z%3 == 2) {
            $class = "primary";
        }
?>                          
                <li class="sep-<?php echo $class; ?>-left medium-thumb ver-space <?php echo ($z%3 != 0)? "sep-bot" : "" ?> span8 no-mar">
                  <div class="span no-mar left-space"><span class="right-space show pull-left"><?php echo $z; ?>.</span>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->showImage('Property', (!empty($property['Attachment'][0]) ? $property['Attachment'][0] : ''), array('dimension' => 'normal_thumb', 'alt' => sprintf(__l('[Image: %s]'), $this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'], false)), 'class' => '', 'title' => $this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'], false))), array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['Property']['slug'], 'admin' => false), array('title'=>$this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'],false),'escape' => false, 'class' => 'show pull-left js-bootstrap-tooltip')) ;?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="span no-mar">
                    <div class="clearfix left-space">
                      <h4 class="span5 no-mar htruncate"> 
                        <?php echo $this->Html->link($property['Property']['title'], array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['Property']['slug'], 'admin' => false), array('title'=>$this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'],false),'escape' => false, 'class' => 'graydarkc js-bootstrap-tooltip'));?>
                     </h4>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="unstyled mob-inline small-thumb mob-clr top-mspace left-space clearfix pull-left">
                        <?php
                            $i = 0;
                            for($i = 0; $i<6; $i++){
                                if(!empty($property['User']['UserComment'][$i])) {
                                    if($i != 5) {
                        ?>
                            <li class="pull-left">
                                <?php echo $this->Html->getUserAvatar($property['User']['UserComment'][$i]['PostedUser'], 'medium_thumb', true, '', 'admin','','',false);?>
                            </li>   
                        <?php
                                    } else {
                        ?>
                            <li class="pull-left sep dc">
                                <?php echo  $this->Html->link(__l("More"), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $property['User']['username'], 'admin' => false, '#Recommendations'), array('target' => '_blank', 'class'=>'more show text-9', 'title' => __l("More"), 'escape' => false));
                                ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    ?>
                            <li class="pull-left sep"></li>
                                    <?php
                                }
                        }   
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li> 
              <?php
                if($z%3 == 0) {
                ?>
                    </ol>   
                    <ol class="text-16 span8 no-mar clearfix unstyled graydarkc">
                <?php
                }
              ?>              
<?php
    }   
?>          
            </ol>  


          </div>
        </div>
<?php
}             
?>
```

I tried to implement the CSS from the first code to the second code and this is my result:

```
<div class="container demo-2">          

<ul class="grid cs-style-2">
                <li>


                        <figure>
                                        <?php
    if(!empty($popular_properties)) {
?>
<?php
    $z = 0;
    foreach($popular_properties as $property) {

?> 


                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->showImage('Property', (!empty($property['Attachment'][0]) ? $property['Attachment'][0] : ''), array('class' => '', 'alt' => sprintf(__l('[Image: %s]'), $this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'], false)), 'class' => '', 'title' => $this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'], false))), array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['Property']['slug'], 'admin' => false), array('title'=>$this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'],false),'escape' => false, 'class' => 'show  ')) ;?>
                        <figcaption>
                            <span><?php echo $this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'], array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['Property']['slug'], 'admin' => false), array('title'=>$this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'],false),'escape' => false, 'class' => ''));?><span>
                            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Book Now <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>', array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['Property']['slug'], 'admin' => false), array('title'=>$this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'],false),'escape' => false, 'class' => ''));?>
                            <li>
                            <figure>
                         <?php
                if($z%3 == 0) {
                ?>
                    </li>  
                    <li >
                <?php
                }
              ?>   <figure>
              </li>           
<?php
    }   
?>          
            </li>  



            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>

            <?php
}             
?>
```

However the result is a mess. You can see a live demo at: http://tinyurl.com/qz8rol2

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved it:

```
         <div class="container block-space">
          <h3 class="dc bot-space bot-mspace"><?php echo __l("Proprietati minunate"); ?></h3>


<div class="container demo-2">          

<ul class="grid cs-style-2">
                <li>


                        <figure>
                                        <?php
    if(!empty($popular_properties)) {
?>
<?php
    $z = 0;
    foreach($popular_properties as $property) {

?> 


                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->showImage('Property', (!empty($property['Attachment'][0]) ? $property['Attachment'][0] : ''), array('class' => '', 'alt' => sprintf(__l('[Image: %s]'), $this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'], false)), 'class' => '', 'title' => $this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'], false))), array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['Property']['slug'], 'admin' => false), array('title'=>$this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'],false),'escape' => false, 'class' => 'show  ')) ;?>
                        <figcaption>
                            <span><?php echo $this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'], array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['Property']['slug'], 'admin' => false), array('title'=>$this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'],false),'escape' => false, 'class' => ''));?><span>
                            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Book Now <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>', array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['Property']['slug'], 'admin' => false), array('title'=>$this->Html->cText($property['Property']['title'],false),'escape' => false, 'class' => ''));?>


                         <?php
                if($z%3 == 0) {
                ?>
                </li>  


                <li><figure>    
                <?php
                }
              ?>   


<?php
    }   
?>          
    </figure> </li>   



            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>

            <?php
}             
?>
```